# Listbox won't update Form with Multiple keys

Tags: sql, ms-access, listbox, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create a Listbox that will let me select a name to change the record I am viewing on a form. I have gotten the Listbox to filter on the First primary key [POCID], but adding criteria on [CustID] in the Listbox's query throws it for a loop.

I have two Tables, Customer and POC. There are many POC's per Customer. With my working Listbox i can see ALL POCs for ALL Customers. I am able to select each name and it will change the record i am looking at on the fields. But I only want to see ALL POCs for each customer. To Accomplish this, i went ahead and threw Criteria on the CustID Field in my query that feeds my Listbox. The criteria is being passed with this: [OpenArgs] from another form.

The Listbox will show me the correct records, but no longer changes the other fields on my form. Is there something i may be overlooking?

**SQL Query Feeding my Listbox**:

```
SELECT Dropdown_Query_POC.ID, POC.Name, POC.CustID
FROM POC
WHERE POC.CustID = [OpenArgs];
```

**AfterUpdate Event on the List Box**

```
Private Sub Combo91_AfterUpdate()
    DoCmd.SearchForRecord , "", acFirst, "[ID] = " & Str(Nz(Screen.ActiveControl, 0)) 
End Sub
```

***EDIT**

Just today I noticed that this only occurs after I add a new record on the form. After I save the record, I then have close out the form and reopen it in a normal edit mode to get the Listbox to work

Comment: never used the screen.activecontrol before, as I always refer to my listbox or control explicity, but you might want to try: `"ID= '" & str(nz(screen.activecontrol,0)) & "'"` since you parameter is for a string

Comment: Line reads as: `DoCmd.SearchForRecord , "", acFirst, "ID= '" & Str(Nz(Screen.ActiveControl, 0)) & "'"` And now it does not work

Comment: Noticed that the objectname is "", perhaps change to name of the form you're searching in.  (Not sure if "" defaults to the current form?)

Comment: I Tried both `Forms!Edit_POC` and `Me!POCID` which is the field with the ID. They both failed

Comment: just put the name of the form in quotes.